# How to extract the 95% confidence bound data in cfit object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I fitted a curve with Matlab which gives the answer:

```
fitresult_hc_fan = 

     General model:
     fitresult_hc_fan(t) = Tss-(Tss-T0)*exp(-t/tau)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       T0 =       71.41  (70.2, 72.61)
       Tss =       25.82  (25.55, 26.09)
       tau =      0.8787  (0.8309, 0.9265)
```

I know I can extract the coefficients by simply using a dot + coefficient name, like:

```
fit_result_hc_fan_T0 = fitresult_hc_fan.T0;
```

but I cannot get that 95% confidence bounds t0.95 out.

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/confint.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.  @VaheTshitoyan

Comment: No worries, glad I could help